Other methods extract the x-coordinates and y-coordinates from a list of multiple coordinate values and list them separately in two individual lists?
x={0.04,0.06,0.04,0.08,0.08,0.05,0.05,0.07,0.07,0.06}
y={0.25,0.4,0.22,0.54,0.51,0.34,0.36,0.46,0.42,0.4}

The two lists above represent sets of x-coordinates and y-coordinates respectively, and they correspond sequentially to form a collection of points where each point consists of paired x and y coordinate values. We can merge them in order using threading into a list format composed of coordinates of points.
x = {0.04, 0.06, 0.04, 0.08, 0.08, 0.05, 0.05, 0.07, 0.07, 0.06}
y = {0.25, 0.4, 0.22, 0.54, 0.51, 0.34, 0.36, 0.46, 0.42, 0.4}
data = Thread@{x, y}


get the coordinates of points.
{{0.04, 0.25}, {0.06, 0.4}, {0.04, 0.22}, {0.08, 0.54}, {0.08, 
  0.51}, {0.05, 0.34}, {0.05, 0.36}, {0.07, 0.46}, {0.07, 
  0.42}, {0.06, 0.4}}


My current question is how to reverse the above operation: given a list composed of sets of coordinates of points, how to separate it into two lists where one lists the x-coordinates in sequence and the other lists the y-coordinates in sequence.
Given the following:
{{0.04, 0.25}, {0.06, 0.4}, {0.04, 0.22}, {0.08, 0.54}, {0.08, 
  0.51}, {0.05, 0.34}, {0.05, 0.36}, {0.07, 0.46}, {0.07, 
  0.42}, {0.06, 0.4}}

to get:
x = {0.04, 0.06, 0.04, 0.08, 0.08, 0.05, 0.05, 0.07, 0.07, 0.06}
y = {0.25, 0.4, 0.22, 0.54, 0.51, 0.34, 0.36, 0.46, 0.42, 0.4}


Is there another approach to solve this problem besides the one mentioned as follows?
list = {{0.04, 0.25}, {0.06, 0.4}, {0.04, 0.22}, {0.08, 0.54}, {0.08, 
    0.51}, {0.05, 0.34}, {0.05, 0.36}, {0.07, 0.46}, {0.07, 
    0.42}, {0.06, 0.4}};
x = list[[All, 1]]
y = list[[All, 2]]



https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A68574+transpose I don't see your effort in understanding the code you've obtained (-1)

Transpose[]
In[9]:= {x, y} =
Transpose[{{0.04, 0.25}, {0.06, 0.4}, {0.04, 0.22}, {0.08,
0.54}, {0.08, 0.51}, {0.05, 0.34}, {0.05, 0.36}, {0.07,
0.46}, {0.07, 0.42}, {0.06, 0.4}}];
In[10]:= x
Out[10]= {0.04, 0.06, 0.04, 0.08, 0.08, 0.05, 0.05, 0.07, 0.07, 0.06}
In[11]:= y
Out[11]= {0.25, 0.4, 0.22, 0.54, 0.51, 0.34, 0.36, 0.46, 0.42, 0.4}

Better way
We can actually just directly set the variables without creating varNames:
{x,y,z,t} = data//Transpose;

Original Post
Your method is perfectly fine for cases with 2 coordinates.
In a case with more coordinates, I wouldn't even bother creating extra variables, and instead just reference list[[All,i]] whenever I need the ith coordinate. But I suppose you could do something like:
ClearAll[x, y, z, t, varNames, data]
varNames = {x, y, z, t};
data = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10, 4}];

MapThread[Set, {varNames, data // Transpose}];

I am not sure if using Set like this has any unintended side effects though.
Edit: To be clean, we should probably also clear out varNames after too because it's just a copy of data (this does not destroy the definitions of x y z and t):
ClearAll[varNames]

